# Copy a specific range every nth number of rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, range

I'm very new to VBA coding and cannot figure out this issue. I tried another solution but found it wouldn't work later down the road. I'm currently testing out this one.

On worksheet "BS growth" I need to read Column A to make sure it says "Asset" If it does I then need to copy and paste the entire rows, excluding A,B & C starting from D5 until D30. The loop then needs to skip 15 cells down and copy the next range of 25 rows (D45:D70, D85:D110, etc) until it no longer says Asset in column A. The first 402 rows in Column A say "Asset," and then the next 300 say "Liability" and the final 200 says "Equity."

I'll then need to paste the data into worksheet "Chart Ref" starting at row A2.

Here is a sample of the data. I am not sure if it is working/embedded properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blP0a.png)

I do not know how to make a loop repeat as needed.

```
Sub ChartReference4()

    Dim ws As Worksheet


    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BS growth")
 
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BS growth").Range("A:A")
        If cell.Value = "Asset" Then

            Range("D5:D30").Select
            'I need this to not be hard coded and only copy from D5 down 25 and then skip 15 cells and repeat the loop
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 'Need all information to right
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Worksheets

        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Currently this code just copies everything in the sheet from column D to the right.

Thanks so much, please comment if this doesnt make sense or I need more information.

Comment: Some mock data would help.

Comment: It's not clear how the position of "Asset" in ColA relates to the position of the 15-row blocks you're copying.

Comment: Furthermore the first block has 25 rows (D5:D30) - all other just 15 (D45:D60, D75:D90) ...

Comment: It is also not clear whether the data you want to copy is on the `BS growth` worksheet or where you are copying the data to..

Comment: Also, when you say entire row, starting at `D5`, do you mean entire row excluding column `A`-`C`?  
        
  And does Column `A` only consist of multiple rows of the word `"Asset"`?

Comment: Hi All, thank you for your questions. I re-edited the post and answered each question accordingly by adding some more detail. I attached a link with the mock data. ColA basically says Asset for the first 400 rows (and then switches to Liabilities), All blocks have 25 rows and skip 15 rows, copying to Chart Ref, and copying and pasting all cells excluding anything in rows A, B and C.